# Appropriate weighting for averages

Tags: mean, weighted-mean

What is the appropriate (or the advantages of disadvantages for each) measure for weighting mortality rates across countries: total population or total number of deaths?

For example, if you have age-standardized cardiovascular disease mortality rates for 5 different-sized but otherwise comparable countries and want to find the mean, what would be the reasons for or appropriateness of weighting by population or number of deaths?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to weight by population, since larger countries will give a more precise estimate of their mortality rate (i.e., larger sample) compared to smaller countries...think China vs Luxembourg.